# Append part of folder name to all .gz within

Tags: bash

I have a folder of data folders with the following structure:

```
sampleName1-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/data1.gz
sampleName1-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/data2.gz
sampleName2-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/data1.gz
```

I want to modify all the data.gz within each sample folder by appending the sample name but not the random numbers to get:

```
sampleName1-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/sampleName1_data1.gz
sampleName1-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/sampleName1_data2.gz
sampleName2-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/sampleName2_data1.gz
```

It seems like this should be a simple mv for loop but I haven't been able to figure out how to pull part of a folder name using basename.

```
for i in */Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/*.gz; do mv $i "fastq""/"${i%%-*}"."`basename $i`; done
```

I couldn't figure out how to make the files stay in their original folder but for my purposes it works to have all the files go to a new folder ("fastq")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the "sampleName" part doesn't include dashes. In that case, use the standard pattern removal expansion: `%%`. That is, suppose your full path (relative to directory root) is stored in `$path`, just do `${path%%-*}` to extract the "sampleName" part. Search for `%%` in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for more details. As a simple example:

```
> path=sampleName1-randomNumbers/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/data1.gz
> echo ${path%%-*}
sampleName1
```

Otherwise, you could also use more advanced substring extraction based on regex. See [BashFAQ/100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) or [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) from the TLDP Advanced Bash Scripting Guide.

**Update**. Here's the full command to perform the job described, and it is entirely native to the shell:

```
for file in */Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/*.gz; do
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/${file%%-*}_${file##*/}"
done
```

Comment: thanks that got me on the correct path.  I've edited my question with the for loop that does what I need

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't figure out how to make the files stay in their original folder"? What prevents you from doing `$(dirname "$i")`? Also,  is your problem solved? If it is, you can accept the answer.

Comment: I didn't try dirname, I was trying different configurations of ${path } with % or #

Comment: Good. I pointed you to `dirname` because you were using `basename` already, and it is easier to understand for people who are new to parameter expansion. But since you asked for it, do note that using parameter expansion instead of  `dirname` and `basename` is more performant, because it is native to the shell and doesn't require forking, which is one of the most expensive operations in shell scripts. I have updated my answer to show you how to do the job entirely natively.

Comment: AH! thanks for your complete example, I wasn't understanding the distinction between %% and % or ## and #